# List<Parent> holding Child element without losing properties C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, casting

I have these classes

```
class Start
{
    public List<Base> list { get; set; }
    public Start() 
    {
        list = new List<Base>();
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public int a { get; set; }
}

class B : Base
{
    public int b;
    public B(int a, int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
}

class C : Base
{
    public int c;
    public C(int a, int c) { this.a = a; this.c = c; }
}
```

I want `list` property of class `Start` to hold instances of class `B` or instances of class `C` (not both together, but it may hold the same type of any of `B` or `C`)
**If possible, I don't want to use Generics**
In C#, This is possible:

```
List<Object> lst = new List<Object>();
lst.Add(1);
list.Add("Text");
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", lst[0], lst[1]);
```

I don't understand why I can't make a similar behavior here:

```
Start s = new Start();
B b = new B(1, 2);
s.list.Add(b);
Console.WriteLine(s.list[0].a); //works
Console.WriteLine(s.list[0].b); //doesn't work
```

Comment: I wonder, is there a specific reason why you don't want to use generics, or is this just a subjective personal dislike of or unfamiliarity with generics?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I'm working with two APIs, each ones response has its own different fileds, but there is one field which is shared to both, and I shared multiple general properties to both (such as Request status, request message and few more things)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace In few functions I don't know which one of the two APIs I will call until some in-real-time things happen, so I don't know which API's result will come back to me, I need to handle both and to deal with each type separately then

Comment: You could probably use generics in a manner that allows you to do that while also making it impossible to accidenatlly add the wrong object type to the List<Base> in the Start instance(s). Let me cook up an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two snippets is that in the first one you are not accessing any type-specific information (fields/properties/methods), i.e. something like the following will not compile too:

```cs
List<Object> lst = new List<Object>();
lst.Add(1);
list.Add("Text");
// will not compile despite string having Length property:
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", lst[0], lst[1].Length);
```

`a` is common property declared in `Base` class, so it is available for every  child of `Base`, if you want to access child specific properties you need to [type test/cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) :

```
Start s = new Start();
B b = new B(1, 2);
s.list.Add(b);
Console.WriteLine(s.list[0].a); //works
if(s.list[0] is B b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.b);
}
```

or make `Start` generic:

```cs
class Start<T> where T: Base
{
    public List<T> list { get; set; }
    public Start() 
    {
        list = new List<T>();
    }
}

var s = new Start<B>();
s.list.Add(new B(1, 2));
Console.WriteLine(s.list[0].b);
```

P.S.

Note that overriding `ToString` in `Base`, `B` and `A` will make `Console.WriteLine("{0}", s.list[0]);` "work":

```cs
class B : Base
{
    // ...
    public override string ToString() => return $"B(A: {a} B: {b})";
}

class C : Base
{
    // ...
    public override string ToString() => return $"C(A: {a} B: {c})";
}

Start s = new Start();
B b = new B(1, 2);
s.list.Add(b);
s.list.Add(new C(4, 2));
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", s.list[0], s.list[1]); // prints "B(A: 1 B: 2) C(A: 4 B: 2)"
```

So possibly you can introduce some method in `Base` which will allow you to use `List<Base>` (hard to tell without knowing actual use case).

Answer (score 1):

The `List<Object>` example is possible because both `int` and `string` inherit from `Object`, which provides a `ToString()` method that is called implicitly on the line that writes the output. That is, no members of either the `int` or `string` types are used in that example that are specific to their own types.

You might accomplish what you need without generics by adding an **interface** that both `B` and `C` can implement, since both the `b` and `c` properties are compatible (they are both `int`s). However, this is clearly a contrived example, and I expect the real code is more complicated. In that case, generics are likely your best option.

Answer (score 1):

because all Base objects dont have 'b' fields

you need to test to see if list[0] is an instance of 'B' and then cast it to a B

```
if (list[0] is B )
{
       Console.WriteLine(((B)(list[0]).b);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments underneath the question, perhaps a combination of both a non-generic interface and a generic `Start` class could work in this scenario.

The non-generic base interface for the generic `Start` class would declare a get-only `List` property as `IReadOnlyList<Base>`. *IReadOnlyList* is co-variant, allowing to return different List<T> instances where *T* is a concrete derived type from `Base`.

```
public interface IStart
{
    IReadOnlyList<Base> List { get; }
}
```

The generic `Start<TBase>` class implements IStart, puts the *IStart.List* property in an explicit interface declaration and declares its own *List* property that is typed as *List<TBase>*.

```
public class Start<TBase> : IStart where TBase : Base
{
    public List<TBase> List { get; set; }

    IReadOnlyList<Base> IStart.List => this.List;

    public Start() 
    {
        List = new List<TBase>();
    }
}
```

Note that both the explicit interface implementation of *IStart.List* and *Start<TBase>*'s own *List* property return the same List<TBase> instance.

This setup makes the following things possible (or impossible, see the code comments):

```
var startC = new Start<C>();

startC.List.Add(new C()); // this works, of course it works

startC.List.Add(new B()); // The compiler will NOT allow this


IStart SomeMethodProducingAStart()
{
   if (someCondition)
       return new Start<B>();
   else
       return new Start<C>();
}

void SomeMethodConsumingAStart(IStart start)
{
    if (start is Start<B> startWithBs)
    {
       // do stuff with startWithBs...
       Console.WriteLine(startWithBs.List[0].a);
       Console.WriteLine(startWithBs.List[0].b);
    }
    else if (start is Start<C> startWithCs)
    {
       // do stuff with startWithCs...
       Console.WriteLine(startWithCs.List[0].a);
       Console.WriteLine(startWithCs.List[0].c);
    }

    // if you don't care about the members specific to either B or C,
    // just do this
    Console.WriteLine(start.List[0].a);

    // since start can be any Start<T>
    // the following is denied by the compiler
    // simply by virtue of IStart.List being an IReadOnlyList
    start.List.Add(new C());    // no can do!
}
```

Whether this approach fits your application scenario well is for you to determine, but it's an approach that tries to avoid granular pattern matching on individual list items and aims at simplifying working with Start instances once they have been pattern-matched/cast to the correct Start<TBase> type.